# Acessar NFC-e através do WebService do sefaz

Tags: web-service, nfe

Olá, necessito acessar os cupons (NFC-e) dos meus clientes do estado de São Paulo. Hoje eu teria acesso aos cupons e a chave pública dos mesmos, porém através do acesso manual no site do sefaz. Eu gostaria de acessá-las via webservice do próprio sefaz e se possível ler em uma extensão XML, seria possível? preciso inicialmente de um certificado da minha empresa para acessar esses cupons via webservice? Obrigado!

Comment: Eduardo, ainda não é possível realizar o download do xml do modelo 65 dos nfces. Não há web services para isto. Somente modelo 55 e 57 atrelado ao modelo 55.

Para outras funcionalidades trabalhe com NFePHP

Comment: Caso precise para modelo 55 posso te passar exemplos e te ajudar

Comment: Muito obrigado @LeandroAlfredo, você poderia me passar exemplos desse modelo 55? eu acabei editando um pouco a pergunta, não precisaria necessariamente realizar o download, porém via webservice conseguir o retorno dessa NFC-e em xml ou qualquer outra extensão que o sefaz me retornasse.

Comment: ok, vou montar a resposta aqui para você

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo, você pode utilizar a biblioteca NFePHP link do gitHub [aqui](https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-nfe)

> Preciso inicialmente de um certificado da minha empresa para acessar esses cupons via webservice?
>   Sim, você precisa do certificado digital para realizar qualquer ação que envolva das SEFAZ's.

Segue exemplo para realizar download da NFe com chave de acesso :

```
use NFePHP\NFe\Tools;
use NFePHP\Common\Certificate;

try {

    $tools = new Tools($configJson, Certificate::readPfx($pfxcontent, $password));
    //só funciona para o modelo 55
    $tools->model('55');
    //este serviço somente opera em ambiente de produção
    $this->tools->setEnvironment(1);
    $chave = '35180174283375000142550010000234761182919182';
    $response = $tools->sefazDownload($chave);
    header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
    echo $response;

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $e->getMessage());
}
```